# Recursive relation in java when only one parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring data jpa with hibernate implementation.

I search to do a recursive relation.

I have an entity Parent.

Paul is parent of Bob who are parent of George

Paul has only one parent, like Bob and George.

How to modelize that in Jpa?

I search to modelize only an unidirectional relation?

Do I need to do

```
@Entity
public class Parent{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Parent parent
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes. What's your question?

Comment: If a parent only has one child, yes. Otherwise it should be a ManyToOne.